# How to install psycopg2 libary in python for PostgreSQL in AWS lambda function?

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, psycopg2

I tried to deploy the package which had psycopg2 library in it to AWS lambda function i'm getting no module error, I have tried this from windows environment which I know is not compatible to aws environment. can anyone help me out on installing the psycopg2 and process of deploying into AWS lambda function. I'm new to AWS. TIA

Answer (score 2):

AWS Lambda's are missing some postgres libraries, and the standard psycopg2 library will not work.

A solution to this is to use a different psycopg2 library from here - https://github.com/jkehler/awslambda-psycopg2 inside of your project, instructions on how to add it as a package within AWS Lambda are in the repo.

Comment: trying this now. curious tho, on his link for the postgresql source code, he's directing to 9.4. currently the most recent is 12. would that make a difference? if not, will it? ill be using this on a lambda function that's trying to connect to a RDS postgres.

Comment: compiled it using the 9.4 at the moment, my issue is when i import the psycopg2 (after renaming the folder as per his instructions), i get a "module 'psycopg2' has no attribute 'connect'". not sure why that is.

Answer (score 0):

1. Build the layer package using the structure "python/lib/python3.9/site-packages".
2. After installing psycopg2-binary, rename the _psycopg.so file under the directory "psycopg2" ("_psycopg.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so "is under the "psycopg" directory).
3. Put the layer into the Python lambda function and add it to the code.